# Extract specific string between under line in R

Tags: r, regex, substring

I have a string like this:

```
Euka_20220607_HD1_Swift_121_h3417.csv
Euka_20220608_HD32_Swift_5426_h87.csv
```

I want to remove `Euka_` , `HD[\d+]` and suffix `.csv` and get:

```
20220607_Swift_121_h3417
20220608_Swift_5426_h87
```

I tried below:

```
sub("\\..*" , "", gsub("Euka_", "", x), x)

> 20220607_HD1_Swift_121_h3417
```

Still can't get what I want. Any one can help? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right path. Here is the correct code:

```
x <- c("Euka_20220607_HD1_Swift_121_h3417.csv", "Euka_20220608_HD32_Swift_5426_h87.csv")

result <- gsub("^Euka_|_HD\\d+|\\.csv$", "", x)
print(result)
[1] "20220607_Swift_121_h3417" "20220608_Swift_5426_h87"
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative:

```r
sub("Euka_(.+)HD\\d+_(.+)\\.csv", "\\1\\2", x)

# [1] "20220607_Swift_121_h3417"
# [2] "20220608_Swift_5426_h87"
```

Answer (score 1):

Please alternatively try the below code

```r
library(stringr)

str_remove_all(text,'(Euka_)|(HD\\d+\\_)|(\\.\\w+)')

[1] "20220607_Swift_121_h3417" "20220608_Swift_5426_h87"
```